# collapsing non-breaking with regular spaces with CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on a large content website, and it's really bugging me that scattered throughout are double spaces, in the format of non-breaking space followed by a regular space, meaning browsers render it as 2 spaces rather than collapsing them as it would with 2 regular spaces.

Is there a way (using css) to collapse the space in this circumstance?

Comment: It would be helpful with some code example...

Comment: don't think it's possible with css but what's wrong with find and replace?

Comment: I'm not sure what an example would show, I simply want to collapse a non-breaking space with a regular one when they appear together.

Answer (score 1):

A non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) is what it is: a non-breaking space, so nothing will help there. A regular space may or may not "collapse" into nothing - that will depend on the encoding of your page. In most cases you won't want to collapse white-spaces, though, as your text would collapse into a block...

So the only solution I see here is to search for the offending `white-space&nbsp;` and `&nbsp;white-space` and remove the `&nbsp;` part, so that you end up with a single white-space.