# Display thin spaces as regular spaces in CSS or find & replace

Tags: html, css, text-rendering

Our content team writes in ms word, and we've been having issues with thin spaces when copying content over. Is there a way to either:

1. Render thin, narrow, and hair spaces as regular spaces
2. Do a find and replace for thin spaces and replace with regular ones

Here are some resources I found on different types of spaces:

- [collapsing non-breaking with regular spaces with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237669/collapsing-non-breaking-with-regular-spaces-with-css)
- http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

Comment: Post the markup that is causing the problem and/or a screeshot.

Comment: Is your site content managed or are you just pasting directly into.  If the former, then most wysiwygs have a paste from word icon which cleans the content if it comes from word.  If the latter, then why not use an online cleaner - [there are quite a lot](https://www.google.com/search?q=clean+html+from+word&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=clean+html+from+word&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3775j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in CSS in a "dirty" way is to use the word-spacing property.

But I recommend to find&replace since a thin space requires 3 bytes to be stored while normal spaces need only 1 byte (in case of UTF-8). The more spaces your content has, the more unneccessary storage is required.